# What is vega, really?

Tags: stochastic-volatility, vega

Assume for now we are working in a stohastic volatility (SV) setting,
$$
dS_r = \sqrt{v_r} S_r dW
$$
and
$$
dv_r = a(v_r,r)dr + b(v_r,r) dZ
$$
with
$$
dWdZ = \rho dr
$$

Let $C(S_t,v_t,t)$ denote the SV price of a claim today. Let's define (variance) vega as the change in the option value if time $t$ variance is shocked/displaced by some amount $\varepsilon$:
$$
v_t \rightarrow v_t' = v_t + \varepsilon
$$
Now let's look at what happens to the instantaneous variance for all $u>t$ after this shock:
\begin{align}
v_u' &= v_t + \varepsilon + \int_t^u d(v_r + \varepsilon) \\
&= v_t + \varepsilon + \int_t^u dv_r \\
&= v_u + \varepsilon
\end{align}

My question is, isn't then
$$
C(S_t,v_t + \varepsilon,t) = E_t [ F(S_T)]
$$
where now 
$$
dS_r = \sqrt{v_r + \varepsilon}\, S_r dW
$$
and
$$
dv_r = a(v_r,r)dr + b(v_r,r) dZ
$$
or is
\begin{align}
d(v_r + \varepsilon) &= a(v_r + \varepsilon,r)dr + b(v_r + \varepsilon,r) dZ \\
&\neq dv_r
\end{align}
an the argument above is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both equations for $S, v$ should remain the same as they govern the evolution of these quantities over time *regardless of initial conditions*. It is the initial condition (unstated here) that must change: $v_0 \rightarrow v_0 + \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, as you say the equations should stay the same, only the initial condition changes. Hence writing $dS_u = \sqrt{v_u + \varepsilon} S_u dW$ is **incorrect**. Agree? That said, I am free to define another type of Vega, let's call it parallel path vega, where now $dS_u = \sqrt{v_u + \varepsilon} S_u dW$, basically this is a vega where the entire variance path is shifted up or down. The down-side of this is that variance can turn negative, but taking the shift size small enough it should be OK. The upside, which I can prove, is that then parallel path vega can be computed model-free.

Comment: Agree and yes I suppose you can define that custom vega concept.